# Get the number of elements within a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, metadata

I am trying to understand the complexity of a large number of flows within a Salesforce environment. I've tried looking at the flowdefinition object, and there is summary of elements of a flow. Is there an easy way to query this, or find this, without having to open every single flow?

Comment: Are you willing to download all flow definitions to your local file system and scan these files? Or do you want to retrieve this information within Salesforce?

Comment: I was looking for an 'onplatform' way to achieve this, so I don't have to download the source files from the org or source control. Doing it in VSCode was my other thought if I cannot achieve it another way.